# controller in textfield do not work (flutter)

Tags: flutter, controller, textfield

I have this controller :

```
final _thermController = TextEditingController();
```

and conect it in that textfield:

```
TextField(
              controller: _thermController)
```

but when I pass the controller, textField show the current error:

```
TextEditingController _thermController
package:projectName/pages/search_page.dart

Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant)
```

anyone know how fix it?

Comment: Probably there is a const keyword somewhere and you have non const value passed to them. Please include full TextField implementation

Comment: Thanks, Hooman, was this!

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the final from the controller:

```
var _thermController = TextEditingController();
```